# How to display each number of a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, paging

basically what I want is display a count until it reaches a certain number, so if I had the number "5" on the screen it would show "1 2 3 4 5".  Or if I had the number "3" it would show "1 2 3".

The reason is because im creating a paging system for my MySQL results.  The code I have so far is

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE subcat = '$conditions'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result1);
$results_per_page = "3";
$num_pages = $num_rows / $results_per_page;
```

So it counts how many results there are, for example we will say 12 results.  It then devides this number by how many results I want shown per page.  In this example its "3".  So the answer is "4".
So I now want to have "1 2 3 4" displayed on the screen, however I want each number to be a link.

How do I do this?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: so... you want to build a pagination?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach( range( 1, $num_pages) as $i) {
    echo '<a href="index.php?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
}
```

Or, an approach suggested by knittl:

```
echo implode( ' | ', array_map( function( $i) {
    return sprintf( '<a href="index.php?page=%d">%d</a>', $i, $i);
}, range( 1, $num_pages)));
```

Prints [something like this](http://viper-7.com/Gi5zgd):

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than a `for` loop? I never thought to use `range()` in this manner; that's why I ask.

Comment: @Matt: I don't think so … it will create an array (probably using a loop internally), then iterate over this array. This code looks more like python than PHP. Using `range` in a functional approach might work better though (some combination of range and array_walk/map, …)

Comment: More efficient? The difference between the two is likely negligible, as no application will bottleneck here, but as knittl points out this will create a temporary array to iterate over. However, you avoid the common mistakes of indexed variables, namely off by one errors.

Comment: @knittl `range` is a valid PHP function. This solution is valid; I just wasn't sure how much more/less efficient a `foreach` is than a `for`.

Comment: @Matt: I never claimed that range was not a valid PHP function. I only meant that the code would fit better in the python world.

Comment: @knittl - That sounds like an extravagant solution that doesn't use a  loop! (explicity) So I added it.

Answer (score 3):

Use a for loop.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $num_pages; $i++){
    echo '<a href="page.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $num_pages; ++$i) {
  printf('<a href="?page=%d">page %d</a>', $i, $i);
}
```